# Dijkstra's Algorithm implementation giving incorrect results

Tags: c#, algorithm, dijkstra

I need some help implementing Dijkstra's Algorithm and was hoping someone would be able to assist me. I have it so that it is printing some of routes but it isn't capturing the correct costs for the path.

Here is my node structure:

```
   class Node
    {
        public enum Color {White, Gray, Black};
        public string Name { get; set; } //city
        public List<NeighborNode> Neighbors { get; set; } //Connected Edges
        public Color nodeColor = Color.White;
        public int timeDiscover { get; set; }//discover time
        public int timeFinish { get; set; } // finish time

        public Node() 
        { 
            Neighbors = new List<NeighborNode>();
        }
        public Node(string n, int discover)
        {
            Neighbors = new List<NeighborNode>();
            this.Name = n;
            timeDiscover = discover;
        }


        public Node(string n, NeighborNode e, decimal m)
        {
            Neighbors = new List<NeighborNode>();
            this.Name = n;
            this.Neighbors.Add(e);
        }

    }

    class NeighborNode
    {
        public Node Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Miles { get; set; } //Track the miles on the neighbor node

        public NeighborNode() { }
        public NeighborNode(Node n, decimal m)
        {
            Name = n;
            Miles = m;
        }

    }
```

Here is my algorithm:

```
   public void DijkstraAlgorithm(List<Node> graph)
    {

        List<DA> _algorithmList = new List<DA>(); //track the node cost/positioning
        Stack<Node> _allCities = new Stack<Node>(); // add all cities into this for examination
        Node _nodeToExamine = new Node(); //this is the node we're currently looking at.
        decimal _cost = 0;

        foreach (var city in graph) // putting these onto a stack for easy manipulation. Probably could have just made this a stack to start
        {
            _allCities.Push(city);
            _algorithmList.Add(new DA(city));
        }

        _nodeToExamine = _allCities.Pop(); //pop off the first node

        while (_allCities.Count != 0) // loop through each city
        {

            foreach (var neighbor in _nodeToExamine.Neighbors) //loop through each neighbor of the node
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _algorithmList.Count; i++) //search the alorithm list for the current neighbor node
                {
                    if (_algorithmList[i].Name.Name == neighbor.Name.Name) //found it
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < _algorithmList.Count; j++) //check for the cost of the parent node
                        {
                            if (_algorithmList[j].Name.Name == _nodeToExamine.Name) //looping through
                            {
                                if (_algorithmList[j].Cost != 100000000) //not infinity
                                    _cost = _algorithmList[j].Cost; //set the cost to be the parent cost

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        _cost = _cost + neighbor.Miles;

                        if (_algorithmList[i].Cost > _cost) // check to make sure the miles are less (better path)
                        {
                            _algorithmList[i].Parent = _nodeToExamine; //set the parent to be the top node
                            _algorithmList[i].Cost = _cost; // set the weight to be correct
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            _cost = 0;
            _nodeToExamine = _allCities.Pop();
        }
    }
```

This is what the graph looks like:
[image]

The graph list node is essentially

> Node -- Neighbor Nodes

So for example:

> Node = Olympia, Neighbor Nodes = Lacey and Tacoma

Comment: Just a tip to reduce the amount of indentation, you can invert your `if`s and use `continue` to jump to the next `i`, eg. `if (_algorithmList[i].Name.Name != neighbor.Name.Name) continue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to rewrite the entire algorithm as it wasn't processing correctly:

```
    public void DijkstraAlgorithm(List<Node> graph)
    {

        List<DA> _algorithmList = new List<DA>(); //track the node cost/positioning
        DA _nodeToExamine = new DA(); //this is the node we're currently looking at.
        bool flag = true; //for exting the while loop later

        foreach (var node in graph)
        {
            _algorithmList.Add(new DA(node));
        }

        foreach (var children in _algorithmList[0].Name.Neighbors) //just starting at the first node
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _algorithmList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (children.Name == _algorithmList[i].Name)
                {
                    _algorithmList[i].Parent = _algorithmList[0].Name;
                    _algorithmList[i].Cost = children.Miles;
                    _algorithmList[0].Complete = true;

                }
            }
        }

        while (flag) //loop through the rest to organize
        {
            _algorithmList = _algorithmList.OrderBy(x => x.Cost).ToList(); //sort by shortest path

            for (int i = 0; i < _algorithmList.Count; i++) //loop through each looking for a node that isn't complete
            {
                if (_algorithmList[i].Complete == false)
                {
                    _nodeToExamine = _algorithmList[i];
                    break;
                }
                if (i == 13) //if the counter reaches 13 then we have completed all nodes and should bail out of the loop
                    flag = false;
            }
            if (_nodeToExamine.Name.Neighbors.Count == 0) //set any nodes that do not have children to be complete
            {
                _nodeToExamine.Complete = true;
            }

            foreach (var children in _nodeToExamine.Name.Neighbors) //loop through the children/neighbors to see if there's one with a shorter path
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _algorithmList.Count; i++) 
                {
                    if (children.Name == _algorithmList[i].Name)
                    {
                        if (_nodeToExamine.Cost + children.Miles < _algorithmList[i].Cost) //found a better path
                        {
                            _algorithmList[i].Parent = _nodeToExamine.Name;
                            _algorithmList[i].Cost = _nodeToExamine.Cost + children.Miles;
                        }
                    }
                }
                _nodeToExamine.Complete = true;
            }
        }

        PrintDijkstraAlgoirthm(_algorithmList);
    }


    public void PrintDijkstraAlgoirthm(List<DA> _finalList)
    {
        foreach (var item in _finalList)
        {
           if (item.Parent != null)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ---> {1}: {2}", item.Parent.Name, item.Name.Name, item.Cost);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that

`_cost = _algorithmList[j].Cost; //set the cost to be the parent cost`

You do a direct assignment of cost, instead of an addition of old and new cost.

Also, the fact that you do

`if (_algorithmList[j].Cost != 100000000) //not infinity`

directly before it means that if the cost of the path is infinity, you do the very opposite - you **add zero** to the cost of the path, making it the least expensive instead of most expensive path.

If you want to check for infinity properly, you have to outright skip taking that path when you inspect its cost, not just skip calculating the cost.

Comment: I'm not following completely. For the first reference (_cost assignment) - I add the cost of the neighbor node to the cost of the parent node below. My thought process behind this is that is what the cost should be... parent node + current node... as in theory the parent node would have the total cost. For the second reference, That is to check if the node has been viewed already (aka, a parent has been found). I'm sorry, I don't quite follow how to improve my code to make it work. Please clarify! Thanks :)

Comment: @Yecats Ok, your algorithm must be wrong in a more subtle way... Please stand by while I comb through it again XD In the mean time, maybe use a debugger/poor man's debugger and see if it does anything suspiciously wrong? You could also test on a very simple graph, such as with only 3-4 edges